# Can I turn off the "no_cookies" option in Google App Engine Launcher (version 1.6.2) on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, google-app-engine, deployment, credentials

When I deploy an application using the Google App Engine Launcher (version 1.6.2) on Windows, the following command options show in the output window:

> Running command: "[u'C:\Python27\pythonw.exe',
>   '-u', u'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py',
>   '--no_cookies', u'--email=xxxx.xxxx@xxxx.xxx', '--passin', 'update',
>   u'C:\path\to\project']"

I want the launcher to store my application-specific password, and I know that it needs to use a cookie to do that, but for some reason the launcher is defaulting to send the "no_cookies" option.

Is there a way to turn this option off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The launcher will always prompt you for credentials, it uses the no_cookies flag to make sure the given credentials are passed and not the one stored in the system.
What you can do is create a batch file that will deploy the application, you can provide credentials using the --email and --passin flags.

Comment: Thanks much... I put the following into a batch file and it prompted me for the password the first time, then seemed to save it somewhere for the next run:`python C:\Progra~1\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py --email=XXXX@XXXX.XXX --passin update PROJECT-FOLDER`

Comment: @ShannonWagner you need to redirect a password file into the command something like this appcfg.py <params> --passin < password_file.txt